# how to copy only one row within cells of multiple rows in LIbreoffice calc?

Tags: excel, formula, libreoffice, calc, libreoffice-basic

I have large number of cells with multiples rows in each cells. Is there any command or regex or formula to copy only 1st or 2nd rows within cells from a large no of cells?

Answer (score 0):

Use Conditional Formatting, C2: L2 Duplicate, then copy this area to the other C3:Cn line, and paste format only.

Duplicates per line will be identified, by the chosen color, delete the discarded one.

Note: Identifies only identical values, if not spelled differently.
[TestFile](https://ask.libreoffice.org/upfiles/15700196025101408.ods)